# From infinite product to infinite sum and a needed expression

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, recursion

We have some function $f_n$ where $f_{\infty}=0$. Now we have a recursive function $t$ where
$$t_{n+1}=\Big(1-f_n\Big)t_n$$

Does this converge?

Determine $t_{\infty}$

Comment: Do you want to find an expression for the limit?

Comment: Yes, in terms of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

For all $n$ we clearly have :

$$1 \geq \left(1-\left ( \frac{3}{4}\right)^{2^np} \right )$$
Hence for all $n$ we have :

$$t_{n+1} \leq t_n$$

Because $t_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ and that the sequence $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing then it converges.

Comment: It converges but not to $0$. Theorem: Let $0\leq a_n<1$ for all $n.$ Then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_n)=0$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty. $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I never said it converges to 0.

Comment: I didn't say that you did. I was just adding a bit to your A, which is correct.